# Spring Boot JPA specification-arg-resolver JOINED Table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to code a Spring Boot application with REST query filter interface.

What I want to achieve:  `localhost:8080/persons/search?age=42&city=Berlin&skilltype=Sport`

Normal filtering on primitive types (String, Int, ...) already works successfully. I have problems when filtering on attributes of another table.

```
@Entity

public class Person {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "age")
  private Integer age;

  @Column(name = "city")
  private String city;

  @Column(name = "skills")
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  private Set<Skill> skills;
```

```
@Entity
public class Skill {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  private String type;
}
```

Controller

```
import net.kaczmarzyk.spring.data.jpa.domain.*;
import net.kaczmarzyk.spring.data.jpa.web.annotation.And;
import net.kaczmarzyk.spring.data.jpa.web.annotation.Join;

  @GetMapping(value = "/persons/search", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersonBySpecification(
      @Join(path = "skills", alias = "s")
          @And({
            @Spec(path = "id", params = "id", spec = Equal.class),
            @Spec(path = "name", params = "name", spec = EqualIgnoreCase.class),
            @Spec(path = "age", params = "age", spec = Equal.class),
            @Spec(path = "city", params = "city", spec = Like.class),
            @Spec(path = "zipCode", params = "zipCode", spec = In.class),
            @Spec(path = "s.name", params = "skillname", spec = In.class),
            @Spec(path = "s.type", params = "skilltype", spec = In.class),
          })
          Specification<Person> spec) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.personService.getPersonBySpecification(spec));
  }
```

Exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "cause" is null`

I am very grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has cost me a lot of time and especially nerves!

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kaczmarzyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>specification-arg-resolver</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is NOT java 16 compatible!

I was able to successfully run the above code in a Java8 Docker container.

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
COPY --from=build /home/app/target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/local/lib/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/app.jar"]
```